# Receive JSON POST data in ZK 6

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl, zk

I am writing an application that will send JSON data via POST with PHP cURL and then the data will be read by ZK 6 application and processed, how can I achieve this? Thanks.

[Edit]

I wanted to create a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Since ZK applications are running in a Servlet Container (e.g. Tomcat/Jetty) you can just create/configure an [HttpServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) implementation in your web.xml and post data to it using any kind of HttpClient ... be it a browser or a command line tool such as cURL or from PHP code.

From a ZK perspective however this doesn't seem to make much sense yet with the given information. A ZK application is running in a browser and depends on an [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

What you didn't tell is, where your application is currently running ... in an IFrame or in a headless browser at server side? Where do you want to send the information? To the overall application or a specific Session or even specific browsertab?